# How to insert into Many Many junction table

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I'm new on symfony and i would like to understand how to add data on my junction table.

I got Mission entity and User Entity.

After clicking on one button i want to add the current idmission and iduser to the junction table named mission_user.

How can i do ?

This is my entity mission :

```html
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\MissionRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MissionRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'mission')]
class Mission
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $titlemission = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $descriptionmission = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $onsetdate = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $deadline = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $budgetmission = null;

    /*#[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $codeapemission = null;*/

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $prioritymission = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Tag::class, inversedBy: 'missions', cascade: ['persist'])]
    #[ORM\JoinTable(name: 'mission_tag')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'mission_id',referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    #[ORM\InverseJoinColumn(name:'tag_id', referencedColumnName: 'id')] //tag_id qui est couplé avec id de tag
    private Collection $tags;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'missions', cascade: ['persist'], fetch:"EAGER")]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private User $iduser;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'missionsassign')]
    #[ORM\JoinTable(name: 'mission_user')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'mission_id',referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    #[ORM\InverseJoinColumn(name:'user_id', referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    private Collection $idmissionassign;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $remote = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $datecreation = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->idmissionassign = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitlemission(): ?string
    {
        return $this->titlemission;
    }

    public function setTitlemission(string $titlemission): self
    {
        $this->titlemission = $titlemission;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescriptionmission(): ?string
    {
        return $this->descriptionmission;
    }

    public function setDescriptionmission(string $descriptionmission): self
    {
        $this->descriptionmission = $descriptionmission;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOnsetdate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->onsetdate;
    }

    public function setOnsetdate(\DateTimeInterface $onsetdate): self
    {
        $this->onsetdate = $onsetdate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeadline(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->deadline;
    }

    public function setDeadline(\DateTimeInterface $deadline): self
    {
        $this->deadline = $deadline;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBudgetmission(): ?int
    {
        return $this->budgetmission;
    }

    public function setBudgetmission(int $budgetmission): self
    {
        $this->budgetmission = $budgetmission;

        return $this;
    }

    /*public function getCodeapemission(): ?string
    {
        return $this->codeapemission;
    }

    public function setCodeapemission(string $codeapemission): self
    {
        $this->codeapemission = $codeapemission;

        return $this;
    }*/

    public function getPrioritymission(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prioritymission;
    }

    public function setPrioritymission(string $prioritymission): self
    {
        $this->prioritymission = $prioritymission;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, tag>
     */
    public function getIdtagmissionassign(): Collection
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    public function addIdtagmissionassign(tag $tags): self
    {
        if (!$this->tags->contains($tags)) {
            $this->tags->add($tags);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeIdtagmissionassign(tag $tags): self
    {
        $this->tags->removeElement($tags);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIduser(): ?user
    {
        return $this->iduser;
    }

    public function setIduser(?user $iduser): self
    {
        $this->iduser = $iduser;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, user>
     */
    public function getIdmissionassign(): Collection
    {
        return $this->idmissionassign;
    }

    public function addIdmissionassign(user $idmissionassign): self
    {
        if (!$this->idmissionassign->contains($idmissionassign)) {
            $this->idmissionassign->add($idmissionassign);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeIdmissionassign(user $idmissionassign): self
    {
        $this->idmissionassign->removeElement($idmissionassign);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRemote(): ?string
    {
        return $this->remote;
    }

    public function setRemote(string $remote): self
    {
        $this->remote = $remote;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->titlemission;
    }

    public function getDatecreation(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->datecreation;
    }

    public function setDatecreation(\DateTimeInterface $datecreation): self
    {
        $this->datecreation = $datecreation;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

This is my user Entity :

```html
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'user')]
#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['email'], message: 'Un compte existe déjà avec cette adresse email')]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 180, unique: true)]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private array $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     */
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?string $password = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $firstname = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 150)]
    private ?string $company = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'boolean')]
    private $isVerified = false;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $companyadress = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'iduser', targetEntity: Mission::class)]
    private Collection $missions;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'iduser', targetEntity: Service::class)]
    private Collection $services;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Service::class, mappedBy: 'idserviceassign')]
    private Collection $servicesassign;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Mission::class, mappedBy: 'idmissionassign')]
    #[ORM\JoinTable(name: 'mission_user')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'user_id',referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    #[ORM\InverseJoinColumn(name:'mission_id', referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    private Collection $missionsassign;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->missions = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->services = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->servicesassign = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->missionsassign = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'USER_DISCOVER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname(string $firstname): self
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCompany(): ?string
    {
        return $this->company;
    }

    public function setCompany(string $company): self
    {
        $this->company = $company;

        return $this;
    }

    public function isVerified(): bool
    {
        return $this->isVerified;
    }

    public function setIsVerified(bool $isVerified): self
    {
        $this->isVerified = $isVerified;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCompanyadress(): ?string
    {
        return $this->companyadress;
    }

    public function setCompanyadress(string $companyadress): self
    {
        $this->companyadress = $companyadress;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Mission>
     */
    public function getMissions(): Collection
    {
        return $this->missions;
    }

    public function addMission(Mission $missions): self
    {
        if (!$this->missions->contains($missions)) {
            $this->missions->add($missions);
            $missions->setIduser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMission(Mission $missions): self
    {
        if ($this->missions->removeElement($missions)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($missions->getIduser() === $this) {
                $missions->setIduser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Service>
     */
    public function getServices(): Collection
    {
        return $this->services;
    }

    public function addService(Service $service): self
    {
        if (!$this->services->contains($service)) {
            $this->services->add($service);
            $service->setIduser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeService(Service $service): self
    {
        if ($this->services->removeElement($service)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($service->getIduser() === $this) {
                $service->setIduser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Service>
     */
    public function getServicesassign(): Collection
    {
        return $this->servicesassign;
    }

    public function addServicesassign(Service $servicesassign): self
    {
        if (!$this->servicesassign->contains($servicesassign)) {
            $this->servicesassign->add($servicesassign);
            $servicesassign->addIdserviceassign($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeServicesassign(Service $servicesassign): self
    {
        if ($this->servicesassign->removeElement($servicesassign)) {
            $servicesassign->removeIdserviceassign($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Mission>
     */
    public function getMissionsassign(): Collection
    {
        return $this->missionsassign;
    }

    public function addMissionsassign(Mission $missionsassign): self
    {
        if (!$this->missionsassign->contains($missionsassign)) {
            $this->missionsassign->add($missionsassign);
            $missionsassign->addIdmissionassign($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMissionsassign(Mission $missionsassign): self
    {
        if ($this->missionsassign->removeElement($missionsassign)) {
            $missionsassign->removeIdmissionassign($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

This is the controller i use to :

```html
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Mission;
use App\Entity\Tag;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\AddMissionFormType;
use App\Form\AddMissionUserType;
use App\Form\RegistrationFormType;
use App\Repository\MissionRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class AccueilProspectorController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/accueil/prospector', name: 'app_accueil_prospector')]
    public function index(Request $request,ManagerRegistry $doctrine,Security $security): Response
    {
        //Récupération de toutes les missions.
        $allmission = $doctrine->getManager()->getRepository(Mission::class)->findAll();
        //dump($allmission[4]);
        //Création du formulaire pour ajouter une mission

        $form = $this->createForm(AddMissionFormType::class, new Mission)->handleRequest($request);
        $missionassigment = $this->createForm(AddMissionUserType::class, new Mission)->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $mission = $form->getData();
            $mission->setIduser($security->getUser());
            $mission->setDatecreation(date_create());
            $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($mission);
            $entityManager->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_accueil_prospector');
        }

//        if($missionassigment->isSubmitted() && $missionassigment->isValid()){
//            $missionuser = $missionassigment->getData();
//            $missionuser->addIdmissionassign($security->getUser());
//            $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();
//            $entityManager->persist($missionuser);
//            $entityManager->flush();
//        }

        return $this->render('accueil_prospector/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'AccueilProspectorController',
            'addmissionForm' => $form->createView(),
            'missionassigment' => $missionassigment->createView(),
            'missionsvalues' => $allmission,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/accueil/prospector/1',name:'app_accueil_mission_1')]
    public function Getmission1d(Request $request,ManagerRegistry $doctrine,Security $security): Response{

        $mission1d = $doctrine->getManager()->getRepository(Mission::class)->selectMission1d();

        $form = $this->createForm(AddMissionFormType::class, new Mission)->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $mission = $form->getData();
            $mission->setIduser($security->getUser());
            $mission->setDatecreation(date_create());
            $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($mission);
            $entityManager->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_accueil_prospector');
        }

        //dump($mission1d);
        return $this->render('accueil_prospector/index.html.twig',[
            'controller_name' => 'AccueilProspectorController',
            'addmissionForm' => $form->createView(),
            'missionsvalues' => $mission1d,
            //'mission1d' => $mission1d
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/accueil/prospector/7',name:'app_accueil_mission_7')]
    public function Getmission7d(Request $request,ManagerRegistry $doctrine,Security $security): Response{

        $mission7d = $doctrine->getManager()->getRepository(Mission::class)->selectMission7d();

        $form = $this->createForm(AddMissionFormType::class, new Mission)->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $mission = $form->getData();
            $mission->setIduser($security->getUser());
            $mission->setDatecreation(date_create());
            $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($mission);
            $entityManager->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_accueil_prospector');
        }

        dump($mission7d);
        return $this->render('accueil_prospector/index.html.twig',[
            'controller_name' => 'AccueilProspectorController',
            'addmissionForm' => $form->createView(),
            'missionsvalues' => $mission7d,
            //'mission1d' => $mission1d
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/accueil/prospector/21',name:'app_accueil_mission_21')]
    public function Getmission3s(Request $request,ManagerRegistry $doctrine,Security $security): Response{

        $mission3s = $doctrine->getManager()->getRepository(Mission::class)->selectMission3s();

        $form = $this->createForm(AddMissionFormType::class, new Mission)->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $mission = $form->getData();
            $mission->setIduser($security->getUser());
            $mission->setDatecreation(date_create());
            $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($mission);
            $entityManager->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_accueil_prospector');
        }

        dump($mission3s);
        return $this->render('accueil_prospector/index.html.twig',[
            'controller_name' => 'AccueilProspectorController',
            'addmissionForm' => $form->createView(),
            'missionsvalues' => $mission3s,
            //'mission1d' => $mission1d
        ]);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to retreive the idmission by the way. Do i need to use ajax with post method or symfony can do the stuff for me ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

To add entries in the joining table between your two tables, you have to add your mission in your user object (or vice versa), then you have to persist the object that has been modified (in the controller):

```
$user->addMissionsassign($mission);
$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Or

```
$mission->addIdmissionassign($user);
$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: How with this code he know that this idmission 1 or to witch is concerned ? I use ajax to join the right controller.

Comment: Before this code implementation you need to match the espected user & mission. Then It will do an insert into your database on the joining table (the user id and mission id) with this informations Doctrine & symfony will match the 'idmission 1' for the user.